# Launch Condition - Check if a service is running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, launch-condition

In VS2008, how can I check whether a windows service is running int he launch condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For details of how to Check that a service is running in Launch Conditions, see [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/windowsmsi/Jun2005/post23457192.asp) thread,

> The most reliable custom action would be a C++ Dll call inserted before the
>   LaunchConditions action in both UI and Execute sequences.
>
> There's an example of one here:
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;253683.
>
> Your custom action code can check for the service running and set a property 
>   for the LaunchConditions.

You can use [ServiceController.GetServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a(v=VS.100).aspx) method to list the services that are running on the local computer.

```
ServiceController[] scServices;
scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();

// Display the list of services currently running on this computer.

Console.WriteLine("Services running on the local computer:");
foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
{
    if (scTemp.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        // Write the service name and the display name
        // for each running service.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("  Service :        {0}", scTemp.ServiceName);
        Console.WriteLine("    Display name:    {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the service as follows:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName");
```

You can check if the service is running by checking the "Status" property. Status returns a value (enum) of type ServiceControllerStatus.